# Using resolved data in subsequent call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am learning how to use `resolve` in `ui-router`. So far I have this in my state (which is a parent state):

```
resolve: {   
    currentApp: function(appService) {
        return appService.retrieve();
    }
}
```

and it calls this function in my `appService`:

```
retrieve: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    Apps.retrieve({}, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject("App could not be retrieved");
        } else {
            app = result;
            deferred.resolve(app);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

The `app` returned is on object with an `id`. Now I would like to run the following code inside the resolve but I'm not sure how I access the resolved app:

```
setId(app.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access it like this:

```
resolve: {   
    currentApp: function(appService) {
        return appService.retrieve().then(
             function(app) {.... SUCCESS ..... },
             function(error) { .... ERROR ..... }
        );
    }
}
```

And/Or you can do the same with the resolved object (`currentApp`) inside your controller:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, currentApp) {
    currentApp.then(
         function(app) { 
              $scope.app = app; 
         },
         function(error) { .... ERROR ..... }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this - very helpful. I do inject `currentApp` inside my controller to set `$scope.app` using `$scope.app = currentApp;` - for some reason though, this part has stopped working???

Comment: `currentApp` is now `undefined`

Comment: @tommyd456 - I have added my answer an example of how to use the resolved object inside the controller.

Comment: I need to use the `resolve` because otherwise I would need to repeat the code in every controller that I have

Comment: So I need to make the `app` available in the controller AND set the id all in the resolve - as it stands `currentApp` (in the Controler) is `undefined`

Comment: Not sure I understand, but the whole point of the resolve is that it return promises  - so you can't pass the actual "app" to the controller, only a promise that resolve the app inside the controller. You can use watcher or just put the app logic inside the "success" function of the promise

Comment: Well I'm just thinking about page refreshes. There are a number of controllers and if a user decides to refresh on any page that uses these controllers then I will need to set the id again. The approach you're suggesting will mean that I need to repeat the code in all of them.

Comment: To clarify, the resolve is in a parent state so it filters down to all children

Comment: so you can create a base state with a controller and save the resolved app to the `$rootScope`, then you'll have access to the app from all the other controllers

Comment: Isn't using the $rootScope defeating the purpose of services though?

Comment: Not when you need to resolve the app in all the other controllers.

Comment: But will the other controllers wait for the base controllers call to `currentApp.then(...`?

Comment: No, they will be able to reference the actual app using `$rootScope.app` (Assuming you'll set it in the `app` field in the $rootScope)

Comment: My original approach was already resolving the app in all other controllers. The only additional requirement is that I set the id using the app from the promise. Just feels a bit of a workaround!

Comment: When you remove the object (whether it's in a base controller, or not), call `setId(app.id);`  **inside** the promise's **success** function

Comment: Thanks - I think wer're going in circles here. I know where to set the id but I guess my question is how to do this efficiently. I was hoping to do this in the resolve but it doesn't appear possible.

Comment: I think what I will try is to set the id from the service function itself.